# How can i do properly deactive/active constraint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am having one view which two constraint i need to toggle.

I had added following constraint

```
chatHalfLeadingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:chatHistoryChildViewController.view
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:self.view
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                   multiplier:1.0
                                   constant:360];

chatFullLeadingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintWithItem:chatHistoryChildViewController.view
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                               toItem:self.view
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                               multiplier:1.0f
                               constant:0.f];

NSLayoutConstraint *traling = [NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintWithItem:chatHistoryChildViewController.view
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                               toItem:self.view
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                               multiplier:1.0f
                               constant:0.f];

NSArray *chatvertConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[childView]|"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:@{@"childView" : chatHistoryChildViewController.view}];

chatFullLeadingConstraint.active = NO;
[self.view addConstraint:chatHalfLeadingConstraint];
[self.view addConstraint:chatFullLeadingConstraint];
[self.view addConstraint:traling];
[self.view addConstraints:chatvertConstraints];
[NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:@[chatFullLeadingConstraint]];
```

I need to deactivate chatFullLeadingConstraint. In UI it looks fine but it shows following error in console.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x145f7c00 H:|-(360)-[UILayoutContainerView:0x145b8e50]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x1458a850 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x145f7c50 H:|-(0)-[UILayoutContainerView:0x145b8e50]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x1458a850 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x145f7c00 H:|-(360)-[UILayoutContainerView:0x145b8e50]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x1458a850 )>
```

**Edited Code**

```
[self.view addConstraint:chatHalfLeadingConstraint];
    //[self.view addConstraint:chatFullLeadingConstraint];
    [self.view addConstraint:traling];
    [self.view addConstraints:chatvertConstraints];
  //  chatFullLeadingConstraint.active = NO;
  //  [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:@[chatFullLeadingConstraint]];


-(void)resizeRightPanelwithBlock:(OnResize)block;{


[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
    if (isFullScreen == false) {
        isFullScreen = true;
        [self.view removeConstraint:chatHalfLeadingConstraint];
        [self.view addConstraint:chatFullLeadingConstraint];
    }else{
        isFullScreen = false;
        [self.view addConstraint:chatHalfLeadingConstraint];
        [self.view removeConstraint:chatFullLeadingConstraint];
    }
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    block(finished);
}];  
}
```

Now when I am trying to do resize it warning comes

Comment: I think you need to inactive constraint after added not before added deactivateConstraints and .active = NO both are same

Comment: No its not a problem

Comment: You could add a identifier to your constraint. Later on you can get this constraint by filter constraints on identifier  and then toggle the active state of this constraint.

Comment: make your chatHalfLeadingConstraint priority low like this in swift 
        chatHalfLeadingConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority.defaultLow

Comment: The warning shows that you have both `chatHalfLeadingConstraint` and `chatFullLeadingConstraint` active at the same time and that these conflict.  You should only have one of these active at any given time. It would be even simpler to have just one constraint and alter the `constant` as required; You can even animate this change for a nice transition.

Comment: I would also add that you don’t need to call `addConstraint`. Setting `active` will automatically add and remove constraints from the correct view, as stated in the documentation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622523-addconstraint?language=objc

Comment: Just hold a reference to any constraint you want to change, and set its `active` and `constant` properties as needed. And as @Paulw11 said, you can even animate these changes if you’d like.

Comment: @Paulw11 I had edited my question as per suggestion it looks good when i load but when i trying to resize warning comes

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove and add constraints. Add a single constraint. Keep a reference to it. Change its constant property to 0 or 360 as required.

```
chatLeadingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintWithItem:chatHistoryChildViewController.view
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                               toItem:self.view
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                               multiplier:1.0
                               constant:360];

NSLayoutConstraint *trailing = [NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintWithItem:chatHistoryChildViewController.view
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                           toItem:self.view
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                           multiplier:1.0f
                           constant:0.f];

NSArray *chatvertConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[childView]|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:@{@"childView" : chatHistoryChildViewController.view}];

[self.view addConstraint:chatLeadingConstraint];
[self.view addConstraint:trailing];
[self.view addConstraints:chatvertConstraints];


-(void)resizeRightPanelToFull:(Bool)full completion:(OnResize)block;{

    chatLeadingConstraint.constant = full ? 0:360

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:[UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut] animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        block(finished);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Also, look into `NSLayoutAnchor` - it is a much nicer way of creating constraints than using `NSLayoutConstraint` directly

Comment: it still problem I am getting warning messaage when this line exucute very first time  chatLeadingConstraint.constant = full ? 0:360 after then it works fine

Comment: What are the conflicted constraints in the warning?

Comment: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
  (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14ed0e20 H:|-(360)-[UILayoutContainerView:0x14eca060]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x14ec5610 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14dea580 H:|-(0)-[UILayoutContainerView:0x14eca060]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x14ec5610 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14ed0e20 H:|-(360)-[UILayoutContainerView:0x14eca060]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x14ec5610 )>

Comment: How are you adding the views?  Are you using a storyboard?  Have you added any constraints there?  Have you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` for any views that you are adding programatically?  The warning shows that you still have two constraints

Comment: Code File : https://gist.github.com/SunnyShah407/a1d8ebec82c137a12b692bbb05f8e901

Comment: That code still has the full & half constraints.  You only need a single constraint.

Comment: @Fogmeister While that is a great resource, the problem here is pretty obvious, they simultaneously have constraints saying that the view should be 0 from the leading edge and 360 from the leading edge.

Comment: @Paulw11 I had removed chatFullLeadingConstraint from the code but still problem

Comment: Can you update the gist to show the code you have based on my answer?

Comment: Where does `ChatHistoryViewController` come from?  Does it come from a `nib` file?  A storyboard scene?  Do you use `initWithFrame`? What is the `UILayoutContainerView`?  You need to provide more information about your view hierarchy and how your app is set up.  I think your constraint problem is coming from another set of constraints

Comment: @Paulw11 true :D Was just adding it as an option :)

Comment: Yes, it is a great resource and a good one to have in the arsenal